# Solve $W:= \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \left(y + \frac{1}{y}\right)^2 \to \inf$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Trying to solve 
\begin{align}
&W:= \left(x + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \left(y + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^2 \to \inf \\
&x+y = 1, \\
&x, y  > 0.
\end{align}
Since $x, y \ne 0$, we can't use AM-GM(it will provide to solution with $x = 1$ and $y = 0$).

But we can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(1 + 1)\cdot\left( \left(x + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \left(y + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^2\right) \ge \dfrac{1}{2}\left( x + y + \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y} \right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x(1 -x)} \right)^2$$

So, since we want to find minimum, wee need $\dfrac{1}{x(1 -x)}$ to be also minumum, i.e. $(x (1 - x)) $ got to be maximum.

Maximum for $(x (1 - x))$ is achieved only when $x= 0.5$, so infimum for W is $12.5$ with $x = y = 0.5$.

Am i right here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  Since $W$ attains the minimum value of $25/2$ for the choice $x = y = 1/2$, we know the lower bound is tight.